# Cannot resolve module 'net' & 'fs' using cors-everywhere

Tags: javascript, webpack, cors, backend, cors-anywhere

I want to use cors-anywhere, but I get that error:

```
ERROR in ./~/cors-anywhere/lib/cors-anywhere.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /Users/<username>/<project>/node_modules/cors-anywhere/lib
 @ ./~/cors-anywhere/lib/cors-anywhere.js 7:10-24

ERROR in ./~/cors-anywhere/lib/cors-anywhere.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /<username>/<project>/node_modules/cors-anywhere/lib
 @ ./~/cors-anywhere/lib/cors-anywhere.js 20:4-17
```

I installed it via

```
npm install cors-everywhere
```

I also added it to the package.json:

```
"cors-anywhere": "^0.4.0"
```

That's my webpack.config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: './build',
    // if the above line does not work, try `path: __dirname + '/build'`
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    target: 'node'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // a regular expression that catches .js files
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000, // most common port
    contentBase: './build',
    inline: true
  }
}
```

I tried to find a solution, but nothing really helps. I also dumped all the node-modules and ran npn install again, installed cors-everwhere again.

Afaik this "fs" and "net" are basic parts of node? So I am a bit confused why they should be missing here...

Would be great if anyone has an idea - thanks!

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: I have a related issue, but for me it seems like my build tools aren't working correctly. When I `npm install` or install other npm modules I get numerous errors in npm at the command line. Do you get any errors when running npm install after removing the node_modules directory?

Answer (score 0):

The `target` property isn't placed correctly, it should be placed in the object root, not in `output`:

```
entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/index.js'],
output: {
  path: './build',
  // if the above line does not work, try `path: __dirname + '/build'`
  filename: 'bundle.js',
},
target: 'node',
...
```